# n-components doesn't seem to truncate the number of components calculated

Tags: scikit-learn, pca

I'm trying to perform Kernal Principal Component Analysis (KPCA) on a large data set that I will want to find the pre-image of after removal of the low energy/high entropy components.

I would had assumed that specifying the n_components parameter would prevent the nxn calculation (and storage thereof), but that doesn't seem to be the case; at least kpca.alphas_ and .lambdas_ still have nxn components stored and calculated.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or can this function not operate similarly to truncated_svd?

I've read up on streaming KPCA approaches that would assuage the memory and processing time issue, but then I would need to auger a way to form the pre-image which I don't feel well equipped to do.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import KernelPCA as KPCA
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs as mb
import numpy as np

X,y=mb(n_samples=400,cluster_std=[1,2,.25,.5,0.1],centers=5,n_features=2)
kpca=KPCA(kernel='rbf',fit_inverse_transform=True,gamma=10,n_components=50)
Xk=kpca.fit_transform(X)
print np.shape(kpca.lambdas_)
```

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me that telling sklearn to fit the inverse might also require all eignvalues/vectors to be calculated.
Without this field, it performs the same way as truncated_svd.

Suppose I'll need to make/discover a pre-image approximation scheme after all.
If you know of any, feel free to post in the comments.